# when gradle testNG groups cmd is triggered it shows null pointer

Tags: java, build.gradle, testng

when `gradle clean test -P testGroups="test"` cmd is used to run tests which has `test` in groups. I get null pointer exception not sure what is wrong,  can someone help here i am stuck for days here

```
FAILED: BotAttributesTest
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sanityTests.BotAttributesTest.BotAttributesTest(BotAttributesTest.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    


it fails at logger line not sure why?

logger declaration below

  public ExtentSparkReporter htmlReporter;
     public static ExtentReports extent;
     public  ExtentTest logger;
     public static WebDriver  wd;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void logger(Method testMethod){
        logger = extent.createTest(testMethod.getName());

        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
```

Comment: Can you please pload a sample project into github, edit your question and add a link to the project in your question that we can use to reproduce the problem ?

Comment: @before was not invoking by default,this was solved by adding alwaysrun=true ,  in testng

Comment: Perhaps you can add that as an answer to your question and accept it, so that the question gets closed?